# Using Stored Procedure result as parameter in where into OLE DB Source

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm starting to working with SSIS and I'm finding a couple of doubts to implement a connection between an Oracle database and my SQL Server.
I have a Stored Procedure in my SQL Server database that return several orders that need to be updated with some information from Oracle database.
So, anyone can help me to think a way to do it? I just need to run my procedure, get the result set and use it in the SQL Command into OLE DB source, in the where clause. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is a bit too broad. SSIS is a perfect tool for it but we cannot design a whole package for you. Please take a look into some SSIS tutorials, see some use cases and come back with specific questions regarding the implementation, should you have any.

Comment: I don't want you create a package to me... I just asked if someone can suggest me a way of how to do that.. If you a God of SSIS, sorry me... I'm learning it so far...

Comment: Don't take me wrong. All I'm saying is that this community likes to see your input first to give you directions then. It is just a bit hard to explain a whole thing from top to bottom and it would be easier for you to understand our directions once you have done some thinking yourself.

Comment: Don't worry.. others guys can give me a idea how can I do to resolve my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have asked a broad question, I will answer with a broad strategy.

Run your stored procedure in an Execute SQL Task and store the results in a variable.   Use that variable to build a second variable with your Oracle query string.   Then use that second variable as the SQL Query in your OLE DB Source.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I've already created a Execute SQL task that save my Full Result Set into an Object data type variable... but when I go to my Data Flow, I couldn't see my variable...  In your suggestion, this second variable I need to create in my Data Flow or Control Flow ( my variable are created into the package scope)? I saw some tutorials that advise me to use a foreach loop container... but it's not making sense to me...

Comment: Yes, since your first variable is Object-type, you will need to iterate through it with a foreach loop and build your second variable in a script task in that loop.   The second variable will have to be package-level and built in the control flow therefore.  OR you could skip the foreach loop and just write a script task that iterates the object variable and builds the string variable.

Comment: Cool... Thank you very much... I will try here and let you know if I was able to implement that...

Comment: Tab.. I was able to implement my process.. Thank you very much for help me!